# Post Deploy MAAS cleanup

Tags: juju, maas

I have a mostly working MAAS cluster.

I'm still learning juju, but while I'm doing that, I wanted to take this opportunity to do some clean-up tasks.

Here are my goals:

1. Configure ntp on the nodes.
2. Set the video mode on the nodes.
3. Set the timezone on the nodes.

Are these juju tasks? Or is this better attacked by mounting the disk image on the MAAS host, and doing the configuration there? If I do it that way, how do I get the nodes to recognize that they have to re-install the image to pickup my changes?

Answer (score 6):

Each node that MAAS prepares for you has your ssh key on it, so you
can automate these tasks using any method that can use ssh as
transport, so that certainly includes Juju.

That pushes you into the realm of customising your charms to do these
set-up tasks, which might fit your expectations, but is going to be
awkward if you're using off-the-shelf charms. However, I'm not the
best person to talk about the Juju side of things, but I can address
the other tasks.

Below I'm talking about MAAS in Quantal (i.e. 12.10, out soon) which
is fairly different from MAAS in 12.04, though there is an upgrade
path. I suspect that none of the following applies to MAAS as shipped
in 12.04.

1. Configure ntp on the nodes.

   By default they'll be set-up to run ntp, using ntp.ubuntu.com. If
   that's not suitable, and you'd rather not add a post-allocation step
   to do it (i.e. configure via ssh as above, once the machine is up
   and running), you may want to change the preseed that MAAS uses.

   Search for the file `preseed_master`; that and the `generic` file in
   the same directory are templates used to generate the final preseed
   sent to booting machines.

   The [Debian
   Installer](http://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/) page links
   to the [manuals](http://d-i.debian.org/manual/). Choose one of those
   and see *Appendix B, Automating the installation using preseeding*
   for an introduction to preseeding.

   Bear in mind that any changes to `preseed_master` or its siblings
   will be overwritten during upgrades, so keep a record of your
   changes around. We will almost certainly be making this whole
   process easier for 13.04.
2. Set the video mode on the nodes.

   Nothing is set in the preseed right now, so you'll have to do this
   in a post-allocation step, or by editing the preseed templates.
3. Set the timezone on the nodes.

   It's set to UTC by default. Do you really want to change this? For
   servers, at least, it's very normal to run with UTC. Your mention of
   video mode setting makes me thing you're using this for desktops
   though, in which case the answer is the same as for #2.