# juju bootstrap time-zone 7:00 hours front of server

Tags: juju

Time Problem

i set the maas server and juju server to same time zone,when ever i try to run juju command  the time stamp ( shown in log) is 7:00 hours front of my servers time.

1) where the juju get time from?!

2) How can I set the juju Time-zone it seems it set on UTC!

Answer (score 0):

[Juju uses UTC](https://askubuntu.com/a/199077/172367). The functionality to change this has not been incorporated into juju for the simple reason that it is very common and useful to run all your servers in UTC.